# How can I manually highlight an item in a JQuery UI menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I am using a [JQuery UI menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/). It works great, but now I have a problem- I need to manually highlight an item from the menu, so it opens and becomes grey as though it has been selected (see below).

[image]

I've tried to force the click manually...

```
$('#menu a:contains("Saarland")')[0].click();
```

...but this just selects the item and closes the menu.

Can anyone suggest a way to do it?

**Update: [I've created the example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQ9vd/2/).**

Comment: Can u elaborate more? Do you want the menu to be opened on another event?

Comment: You're trying to use a jQuery method on a DOM element.  Remove the [0] and it should work....  `$('#menu a:contains("Saarland")').click();`

Comment: Yes. Let's say it's simply a button-click. You click a button called "select Saarland" and "Saarland" becomes selected.

Comment: @Archer Behaves the same without the [0]. Sorry.

Comment: I see now that you just want the menu opened, and not to click an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure who this will help, but I've found a workaround.

I set the `ui-state-focus` and `ui-state-active` classes manually ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQ9vd/33/)).

It's pretty ugly but it seems to be the best solution there is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on it, you need to make sure that you `mousemove` it.

```
$('#menu a:contains("Delphi")').eq(0).mousemove();
$('#menu a:contains("Saarland")').eq(0).mousemove();
```

Have a look the above code, play around with it. Best of luck!

**Tip:** You might also want to try and give IDs to your elements, for better scoping.

Comment: They automatically get assigned ids. So I could do `$('#ui-id-10')` instead of `$('#menu a:contains("Delphi")')`

Comment: Seems a sensible approach but `.mouseover()` doesn't seem to be doing anything. Not sure why.

Comment: I am sorry, use `.mousemove()`

Comment: Sorry. `.mousemove()` doesn't seem to be doing anything either.